# Ubuntu OS on SSD and swap on HDD

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd, swap

I'm planning to install a SSD in the CD-drive of my laptop. After this install i will be left with a 500 GB HDD and a 120 GB SSD . 
I would like to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.1 on the SSD and install the SWAP partition on the HDD to increase the life of the SSD. How to do achieve this during installation.
My laptop specs are an AMD A6 processor with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: Where did you get the notion that storing swap on hdd will save the life of the ssd? or rather storing swap on ssd will destroy its life?

Comment: [Modern SSD's have lifespans comparable to or better than HDD's](https://www.ontrack.com/blog/2018/02/07/how-long-do-ssds-really-last/), so just put the swap on the SSD. See also: [Why no swap partitions on SSD drives?](https://askubuntu.com/q/652337/301745)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap on SSD: partition or file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059108/swap-on-ssd-partition-or-file)